# Is there a way to use 32-bit float instead of 64-bit in R dataframes?

Tags: r

The issue I'm having is related to memory. I'm doing financial calculations on dollar amounts and currently my float precision is 64-bits. I'd like to reduce the precision down to at least 32-bits but so far have not found a way to specify this in R. Ideally, this would just be applied to a dataframe that has a number of columns some are ints and some are floats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is not -- at least not in 'base R' which has only one `integer` and `numeric` (floating point) type each, and their sizes are fixed.

You can inspect them (and more) via `.Machine` -- see `help(".Machine")`.

Now, for your dollar amounts you could of course resort to expressing things in cents instead in which case you could `integer` -- which is generally half the size of `numeric`.

Comment: There is the [float package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/float/index.html). But from my tests so far it is slower than standard num(double) except for large matrices (I am using OpenBLAS). I am tempted to move to numpy when supports even float16.

Comment: I guess this question was about float32 in dataframes and not float32 in general in R.

Answer (score 1):

The following converts all numeric columns in `numeric_df` to float32

```
library(float)
library(purrr)

float32_df <- purrr::modify_if(numeric_df, is.numeric, as.float)
```

Comment: Not true; `numeric` is a cover for both `int` and `float`.  The size of these will be determined by your machine / installation type.  (64bit vs 32bit)

Comment: OP is specifically referring to doing 32-bit floating point arithmetic on a 64-bit machine, which means `numeric` will default to 64-bit. Could you elaborate on why the above doesn't work?